# Divergence of Electric field is zero iff the electric field is a pure Faraday one?

Tags: electromagnetism, classical-electrodynamics, gauss-law

Reference: Introduction to ELectrodynamics (D.J Griffiths)

[image]

Divergence of Electric field is zero iff the electric field is a pure faraday one?

What if it isn't?

Why does this condition have to be imposed on the field for its divergence to be zero?

Comment: You do not have to impose it to get a divergence free field, but if you are sure that the source is a curl and only a curl you can be sure that it is divergence free. It is [sufficient but not necessary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Necessity_and_sufficiency).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gauss's law says $$ \nabla \cdot \vec{E} = 4\pi\rho$$ where $\rho$ is the charge density (CGS units). If there are no charges around then $\rho = 0$ and you have a divergence-less electric field. That's the case for a pure Faraday field: it's produced by a changing $\vec{B}$ without any charges being anywhere in the vicinity. But it's not always true: if there are charges around then the divergence is *not* zero.